# Can't recover accidentally deleted project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, recovery

I was working on a project in IntelliJ, where I put in some code to delete some files from my project. This accidentally deleted the whole project from the filesystem (Windows 10). The only file left is the `.idea` directory that probably stores some IntelliJ configuration. The `Local History` option in IntelliJ has been disabled ever since (which means it wiped the Local History of this project), so there is no way of recovering the project via Local History either.

I used recovery programs like Recuva and EaseUS which for some reason didn't recover the lost files (EaseUS in particular shows files from 2 or 3 days ago instead of today).

I also doubt I can recover these files via Git since Git does not use a single file to store its history.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ...So you didn't put the source code in source control?  You disabled the feature that lets IntelliJ at least somewhat recover from this?  All I can say is, I pray that you have a back up somewhere else...you can't recover files if you didn't make any provisions to recover files.

Comment: Have you verified that the deleted files didn't just go to the Recycle Bin? (Unlikely but possible, and easy to check.)

Comment: Also, did you happen to have a jar or the class files deployed anywhere else outside of the project? If so you could decompile them. Not ideal, but possibly better than nothing, and I think Intellij Idea has a built in decompiler.

Comment: see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035963/how-do-i-recover-previous-local-histories)